# visualstudio malloc ERROR_INVALID_ACCESS

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, malloc

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 1000;
    int count = 1;
    int newlen = 1;
    int oldlen = 10;
    char *result = NULL;
    int total = 0;

    /* case 1 */
    total = i + 1 + count * (newlen - oldlen);
    printf("case 1 start\n");
    result = (char *)malloc(total);
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    free(result);
    printf("case 1 success\n");


    /* case 2 */
    printf("case 2 start\n");
    result = (char *)malloc(i + 1 + count * (newlen - oldlen));
    free(result);
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    printf("case 2 success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Why has `malloc()` failed?

maybe `(newlen - oldlen)` is negative or `count * (minus number)`?

Comment: When I run your program, both case 1 and case 2 succeed. What exactly happens when you run it?

Comment: I can't reproduce. You need `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: I think you hit undefined behavior here `free(result);
    if (result == NULL)`. Try moving the `free` after the `if`

Comment: @CoolGuy well, it's checking for the pointer, not contents, so no UB, at least. Certainly does not make sense, agree.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm confused... After `free`ing, `result` becomes a dangling pointer and checking it is UB, right? Its like `char* result; if(result == NULL) { ...`, right?

Comment: @CoolGuy Well, what you're assuming is not guaranteed. It is only forbidden to access the memory pointed to by the pointer. _result becomes a dangling pointer_ we cannot say for certain, it depends on the implementation.

Comment: I've just reproduced the problem with visual studio 2015, the second case is not working

Comment: but doing like following solves the problem: `result = (char *)malloc((i + 1 + count * (newlen - oldlen)) * sizeof(char));`

Comment: of course `sizeof(char)` equals to 1 but like that, there is no issue anymore

Comment: @2501 `1000 + 1 + 1 * (1 - 10)` = `1001 - 9` = `992` = positive.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks. I assumed `i` has the value 0. Why would someone set it to 1000...

Comment: @H.DJEMAI Do you solved this problem?

Comment: @CoolGuy yeah~ it's my mistake but I want to know problem (   result = (char *)malloc((i + 1 + count * (newlen - oldlen)) * sizeof(char));    )

Comment: @HyungWooJu Remove the casts from `malloc`. They're completely redundant. As for the problem, I can't find anything wrong with your code. Compiles and runs fine on GCC. I don't have VC15 to test, either. So, sorry. I can't spot the problem. BTW, it would be better if you copy-pasted the output you get on running the code.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you, defined in the "stdafx.h" ^^

Comment: @CoolGuy yes, this code is no problem on GCC. But I known problem on VC2013.... T.T   thank you guy~ have a good time.